# Create an XML according to an XSD in Oracle

Tags: xml, oracle, xsd

I am currently checking if its possible to generate an xml using oracle out of tables found within the database using a pre-defined xsd file.

What package would i need for this.

Regards

Carl

Comment: Always add a version number when talking about Oracle database. Lots of differences between versions!

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply it's ORACLE 10g that i'm working on

Comment: And be specific ;-) There's 10g Release 1, Release 2, .. Anyway, see the answer. Shouldn't be so many differences between the 10g releases regarding these features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DBMS_XMLSCHEMA (among others) will be of help.

See [this tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B14117_01/appdev.101/b10790/toc.htm) on how to proceed. (The main source for your solution would be in chapter 5 if I'm not mistaken.)